# Handling of toDataURL - convert convascontext into canvashtml

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jspdf, html2canvas, todataurl

I go through my HTML and convert it into Canvas.

```
for (const element of htmlData) {
    var input = document.getElementById(element);
    allPromises.push(html2canvas(input));
}
```

In the next step I go througt my array of Promises, try to crop the canvas into a special size and write it into a PDF with jsPDF.

```
Promise.all(allPromises).then((response) => {
     response.forEach((input) => {
         var croppedImage = cropImg(input);
         imgData = croppedImage.toDataURL('image/jpeg', 1.0);
         insertImg(imgData, imgWidth_mm, imgHeight_mm);
    }
}
```

The function I use for cropping looks like:

```
function cropImg(image) {
    var ctx = image.getContext('2d');
    ctx.drawImage(image, 20, 20, 50, 50, 0, 0, 50, 50);
    return ctx;
}
```

Unfortunatly I get the errormassage: croppedImage.toDataURL is not a function
It looks like the `.toDataURL` function can't deal the raw context of the canvas I give to it. Any suggestions how I can fix this? If I don't crop the Canvas everything is fine.

Comment: `toDataURL` is a method on the `canvas`, not the `context`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCanvasElement/toDataURL So simply return the `image` and it should be fixed. Note that you are modifying this image on the fly - so you are overwriting your original immediately when cropping.

Comment: True, the errormessage is fixed, but the cropping has no effect on if I change it to: `return image`

Comment: Are you sure you are not deceived by your own eyes here? Cropping should definitely work, and should apply to your existing canvas. Of course, _you havent cleared the canvas_, so you are just drawing on top. If what you are drawing is potentially empty, you might be fooled into thinking nothing is happening. Personally, I would definitely use a fresh canvas for my crop and return that. That's all I can say - there doesn't appear to be an issue with the code here. Please try to come up with a very clear test case so you can be certain it's not working.

Answer (score 0):

The code is right, just the values for cropping are wrong.

Edit: somethinghere is right. I habe to pass the image via `return image`